# How to get Google account to automatically forward mail?

Tags: email, gmail

I used to have a gmail account that was a convenient alias.  It was set up to automatically forward mail it received to a special email address for that purpose at my own SMTP server.  For example, people would send to blahblah@gmail.com, and that mail would automatically go to myblah@mydomain.com.  I only logged into the gmail account for administration purposes, and received all the mail via myblah@mydomain.com.  Everything worked as I wanted it to.

However, last year Google made some change saying I needed to convert my gmail account to a "Google account".  Unfortunately, that was very poorly defined, and it was not clear at all what that really meant, but it seemed the existing gmail account was going to go away.  So, I converted as asked.

Now email sent to blahblah@gmail.com gets stuck there.  I can see it if I log in, but I don't want to.  I went thru all (I think) menus and settings, but didn't find anything that looked like a way to tell it to forward or copy mail to some external address.  There is a way to "add" a mail address, but that seems to be for aliasing the From: field, not for automatic forwarding.

**How do I set up a Google account to automatically forward mail to a different non-Google email address?**

### Response to comments:

> I too received that notice back then, but they left my gmail account the same so I use the "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab in gmail

That's exactly the problem.  I can find no such thing now that it's a "Google account", whatever that really means.

> I donde see why you can't do the same, please share an image to see your interface.

Here are all the choices along the left side.  The tabs up top are only for reading mail, marking as read, etc.  This is where settings and options seem to be:

[image]

Comment: mmm , I too received that notice back then, but they left my gmail account the same, so I use the  "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab in gmail, I donde see why you can't do the same, please share an image to see your interface.

Comment: @arana: See addition to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the COG at the right then select settings [image: gmail settings for forwarding]
Then in the Forwarding TAB you have many options:
[image: Gmail Forward Tab]

Settings are all there, also for for configuring imap and pop options

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see that somehow.  I guess what you call tabs up top just looked like noise and my brain filtered them out.